# How to bring all elements down with a header slide up/down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using CSS to bring down a header element when the user hovers over it. Is it possible to also bring down the rest of the page so that the header overlaps absolutely nothing? How would this be done?

Example of header here: http://dev.handyvet.org/VetProsDevSite/_MASTER/views/vetpro%20users/vet_pro_registration_3.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the height of the nav div, like this:

```
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.active {
  height: 200px;
}
```

I made you a very simple fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rnc8L53L/

I used jQuery to toggle the **.active** class, on the nav when the button is pressed. The .active class overrides the "height:50px" rule , which is the initial state of the nav class.

It's just a very simple example that. It can be done with Javascript too but the event handling is a little more complex. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the whole page instead of header. Set negative top margin for page as default and decrease it's value when you need it